# For finite sets (groups) are order, size, cardinality and power the same thing?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, permutations, definition

In section IB3.5, beginning on page 186 of [The Fundamentals of Mathematics, Volume 1](https://archive.org/stream/MyStuff38/Behnke%2C%20Bachmann%2C%20Fladt%20%26%20Suss%20%5BEds.%5D%20-%20Fundamentals%20of%20Mathematics%20Vol.1%2C%20The%20Real%20Number%20System%20and%20Algebra%5BMIT%20Press%2C%20555p%5D#page/n7/mode/2up), the terms *order* and *power* of a finite group are used. In the first part of the book the power of a finite group is said to be its cardinality which, for a finite set is the whole number of elements in the set.  That is what I like to call the *size* of the set.  I'm not sure what to make of

> the order of a subgroup of a finite group $\mathfrak{G}$ is always a factor of the order of $\mathfrak{G}$.

I believe it simply means *the number of elements in a subgroup of $\mathfrak{G}$ will always divide evenly into the number of elements in $\mathfrak{G}$*.

At this point we apparently have *index, size, order, power and cardinality* used to indicate the number of elements in a set under specific condition.

**Am I correct in understanding that *power* and *order* mean the same thing in this context, and that thing is the number of elements in the set?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not heard "index" used to describe the cardinality of a group. The index of *a subgroup of* a given group is the number of cosets of the subgroup *(or the size of the quotient group, in case the subgroup is normal)*, but that's not the same thing.

Meanwhile, while I've heard "power" used to mean the cardinality of a set, I've not seen it used that way around groups. It's also an older term, and modern texts don't use it as far as I can tell.

One does need to be a bit careful about "order" - while the order of a group (finite or otherwise) is indeed its cardinality, we also talk about the orders of *an element of* a given group (= the cardinality of the subgroup generated by that element). So e.g. we can have a group of order $\aleph_0$ with elements of order $17$.

---

So tl;dr: with the exception of "index" (as far as I know) they do mean the same thing, but "power" is archaic and mostly set-theoretic and I'd avoid its use in *all* contexts.